# JUnit runnable tests using only interfaces

Tags: java, unit-testing, interface, junit

I am trying to get my head around a task I've been asked to do. I usually write unit tests in the form of Expected Input -> Expected Output, black box testing.

But I have been given a task where I have minimal interfaces and I need to produce some runnable unit-tests using only the interfaces. Note that the interfaces will have an input and output of sorts, but I don't have any implementation of the input objects. The interface for the input data is:

```
public interface InputObject { }
```

My question is, how do you write a unit test with 0 implemented elements and no way to form input data?

Comment: You don't. That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not going crazy right? I don't know everything about the topic, but it seems like I've been assigned an impossible task.


I ended up just making mock private implementations of all the interfaces and showed that I knew how to write:

    @Test

Answer (score 0):

This "doesn't make any sense" - Compliments of JB Nizet, above.

If you are trying to do this, you're doing it wrong.